# DAX returning value based on SUM of multiple rows in other table

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

Good evening all!!

Here's a fun one.  I've been pouring through some other posts and it feels like there are many permutations of this scenario but none that span tables, so I'm looking for some input.

Consider the following:

Table A has two fields:  ID and TYPE.  TYPE will be our value to populate.

ID       Type
1
2
3

Table B has two fields:  ASSOCIATED ID and HOURS.

Associated ID      Hours
1                  24
1                  0
2                  10
2                  38
3                  50
3                  25

The requirement is to return a value of "LESS THAN 25" or "GREATER THAN 25" for TYPE in TABLE A based on the SUM of the HOURS in TABLE B for the ASSOCIATED ID.  Ex: ASSOCIATED ID "1" in TABLE has value 24 and 0 for a sum of 24, returning "LESS THAN 25" for TYPE in item ID 1 in TABLE A.

Any and all suggestions will be attempted, thank you so much to the community for taking a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have a relationship between the two tables by using the ID.  Then enter this formula into a column in the ID table:

```
Type:=if(calculate(sum(TableB[Hours]))>25,"25 or More","Less than 25")
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oh sheesh.  Yes, I was way overthinking this.  Thanks Jenn, this worked as expected.  I always forget you can use the CALCULATE function in a column.  You saved me.

Comment: I'm glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one on 1-TYPE: (I am considering A1 Cell as the beginning of your table for both table, just place the real position)

`=IF(SUMIF(TableB!$A$2:$A$7,"="&A2,TableB!$B$2:$B$7)>=25,"GREATER THAN 25","LESS THAN 25")`

Then drag it down.